# CentOS - updating sysconfig

Tags: centos

How can i update the `NM_CONTROLLED` to `no` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`?
Sorry, I am new to CentOS and VIM or VI editor.
I am trying to fix `PYCURL ERROR 6`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issue with `Vim`, maybe you want to start with something easier to use, and install the `nano` editor:

```
yum install nano
```

You can open the file in `nano` as superuser like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

Edit what you want and close the editor by pressing `CTRL+X` and confirming the file save operation.

**Tip 1:** for searching inside a file press `CTRL+W`
**Tip 2:** on the bottom of the screen you can find the shortcuts to most commands you need.

If you want to take time and learn `Vim`, you can start with some basic introductions like [this (interactive)](http://www.openvim.com/tutorial.html) or [this](http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/vim_tutorial.html), or simply using Google.

Comment: Try to install nano shows:

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
could not retrieve mirror list

14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - " coudn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base

Comment: This is a chicken and the egg problem obviously. You will have to use `Vim` then. Check the links about `Vim` usage i provided.

Answer (score 0):

remove NetworkManager package

```
yum remove NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try a sed (you should learn some vi though) this is not something i would not usually tell someone to do this but your file is automagically backed up to file.bak  when invoking -i.NAME

`sed -i.bak 's/^NM_CONTROLLED=.*/NM_CONTROLLED=no/' /path/to/your/file`